# Titanium Android Screen Orientation

Tags: android, titanium

I have made an Android app using Titanium. The screen rotates when device rotate, how can i stop window/screen orientation in Android app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in the Android Manifest file in the `<activity>` element.

See this: [Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: Manifest file in build folder? if it is then this file over writes on each build.

Comment: @Zeeshan: Manifest file resides in the root folder of your project in Eclipse. Its name is `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I spent my whole day to solve this stupid issue, finally i found the solution to solve the android orientation issue.

Please refer to link [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Orientation-section-29004932_Orientation-LimitingorientationmodesonAndroid). The article is helpful and clearly stated step by step how to implement.

This also solved the splash screen orientation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this in you app.tss or in the tss file of the concerned screen

```
"Window":{
    orientationModes : [Titanium.UI.PORTRAIT]
}
```