# Titanium Mobile orientation on Android

Tags: android, titanium

How do I set the screen orientation to portrait only on Android device using Titanium Studio?

Comment: I have seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348602/titanium-android-screen-orientation and it does not help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example project in the KitchenSink; Phone -> Orientation -> "Allow Landscape Only"

Comment: For the record (anyone witht the same issue) I had tried these methods but with no success until I rolled back to SDK 1.6.1 rather than SDK 1.7.1

Answer (score 0):

This works with SDK 1.8.2:

Create directory `platform/android/` in your project directory. Find AndroidManifest.xml in build/android/ , copy and save it in `platform/android/`.

Edit platform/android/AndroidManifest.xml and replace all values of 'android:configChanges' attribute
 to :

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
```

and add 'android:screenOrientation' attribute in all 'activity' tags.

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```